# How to print byte array

Tags: java, arrays, httpresponse

I am trying to print some data which is in an array format. But while printing I am loosing my initial byte of the array which I need. How can I get that?

```
 rray
 (
   [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [company_category] => Company limited by Shares
        [email_id] => example@domain.com
        [last_processed] => 2016-07-01T08:42:34Z
        [company_class] => Public
        [country] => 
     )
 )
```

As you will be seeing that starting of the output should have be "Array" but it is not. What am I doing wrong here. As I am sending a request to a specific URL and getting a response from it. Below is the code I use to get the reponse

```
HttpEntity entity = CloseableHttpResponse.getEntity();
String response = EntityUtils.toString(entity,"UTF-8");
System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: you must post the relevant code: `EntityUtils.toString`

Comment: you are converting `img` to `byte array` and then store that in `String` right?

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString(org.apache.http.HttpEntity,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: Is the code at any point trying to remove the Unicode BOM character at source begin? Or are you using "\r" as line separator somewhere? Or you have a pretty printer that does wrong indenting.

Comment: According to the javadocs @MarkoTopolnik kindly linked to, `EntityUtils.toString` will use the charset in the entity over the one provided.  Take a look at the the entity, what's the charset?  I have a hunch it maybe one that has a byte order mark.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: It could be the byte order mark character only..but I am not being able to find that..can anybody tell me which type of array it is by looking at the syntax..it seems normal array..but i doubt.

Comment: Could anybody tell me how to read that "email id" content..I want the value associated with it.